# mysql select distinct while ignoring one column

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following problem: I have a table `import_data`

The table is enriched something like this

```
|  id  |  profile_id  |  sku  |  vendor  | price |  importRun  |
|  1   |     39       |  123  |  myVen   |  2.0  |      1      |
|  2   |     39       |  456  |  myVen   |  2.0  |      1      |
|  3   |     39       |  123  |  myVen   |  3.0  |      2      |
```

What I need to get is an output of all elements, but only **once**. Every sku must be unique. To make it even worse, I need the newest data, if they are redundant.

My output should be like this:

```
|  id  |  profile_id  |  sku  |  vendor  | price |  importRun  |
|  2   |     39       |  456  |  myVen   |  2.0  |      1      |
|  3   |     39       |  123  |  myVen   |  3.0  |      2      |
```

**Short Summary about the structure**:

ID = PK 
sku = a unique identifier for an article 
importRun = Needed for comparision.

So, to explain it: I have an import-script, which reads a given CSV-file and imports all articles listed in it. I get this CSV-file in a regular period (once a week). I need to collect all data and save it, to create a price-evolution later on.

After every Import, I increment the number of **importRun**, so that no information is lost (remember, I can't use `REPLACE INTO` or `INSERT IGNORE`.

Now, when I export it, I need the newest Data, if a SKU occures multiple times. In this case, the SKU `123` is inserted 2 times on 2 different runs. That means, since my newest Run had the number 2, I need this tupel (and ignore the first one).

When I work with `DISINCT`, it would still output the same table, since they aren't distinct at all, because importRun differs.

I should be able to use `GROUP BY`, but I couldn't figure out which value will be taken, the first- or the last one? (importRun 1 or 2)

**Update 1**

Followed by the idea of @mitkosoft, I tried the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.*
FROM import_data t1
INNER JOIN import_profiles imp on t1.profile_id = imp.id
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT sku, MAX(importRun) AS importRun
    FROM import_data
    GROUP BY sku ) t2
ON t1.sku = t2.sku
WHERE imp.creditornr = 73329
AND t1.vendor = 'rackmountit'
AND t1.importRun = t2.importRun
```

** Update 2 **
I added the complete Structures for all tables, which are relevant.

*Import-Data:*
    | [image]

*Import-Profiles*
    [image]
But i still get duplicates :/

Comment: how do you determinine which row is latest one into import_data table when importRun is the same? as far I can see, `sku` is pretty unique? in other words, which line from import_data must be taken for `profile_id=26` as importRun is 1 everywhere?

Comment: In this case, every line should be taken, since the sku differs. If the `sku` is the same, I have a mapping (which works already I think). It might be however, that there are some entries with the exact same data (except the id) - these are the ones, I need unique. Is that understandable?

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to determine `MAX(importRun)` for each `sku`:

```
SELECT
    t1.*
FROM
    import_data t1
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT sku, MAX(importRun) AS importRun FROM import_data GROUP BY sku
    ) t2 
    ON t1.sku = t2.sku 
    AND t1.importRun = t2.importRun
```

Output is:

```
+----+------------+-----+--------+-------+-----------+
| id | profile_id | sku | vendor | price | importRun |
+----+------------+-----+--------+-------+-----------+
|  2 |         39 | 456 | myVen  | 2.0   |         1 |
|  3 |         39 | 123 | myVen  | 3.0   |         2 |
+----+------------+-----+--------+-------+-----------+
2 rows in set
```

Comment: Hmm.. for some reason that didn't do the trick, even though it looks correct. Please see updated question for my current query

Comment: Well, my SQL was based on your input, now I see additional table in your query, so better provide real data from all involved tables.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, I added the table. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could join on the same table where sku = sku